# Freemarker encoding - question marks in the place of accented characters

Tags: java, freemarker

I am trying to print accented characters with Freemarker, but in the place of accented characters, I get only question marks. I have verified, that following statement holds:

```
 "UTF-8" == Environment.getCurrentEnvironment().getConfiguration().getDefaultEncoding()
```

I can easily see, that the accented characters are correctly held in the variable before giving it to the template.

My freemarker context can be found here: https://gist.github.com/1975239

For instance instead of:

```
 Jedinečný živý koncert, kde nejen, že uslyšíte, ale i uvidíte splynutí metalové kapely s padesátičlenným orchestrem včetně.
```

I keep getting:

```
 Jedine?ný ?ivý koncert, kde nejen, ?e usly?íte, ale i uvidíte splynutí metalové kapely s padesáti?lenným orchestrem v?etn?.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeMarker always treats text as UNICODE, so it doesn't generate question marks. Since the accented letters aren't coming from the templates (if I understand it well), it must be your output encoding that's improper. See also: http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_questionmark

BTW, `getDefaultEncoding()` has no role in this. That influences the decoding used when you load the templates, but you are saying that the accented characters aren't coming from the template file, also I don't think you can get `?`-s from decoding (unless, for invalid UTF-8 byte sequences). As of the encoding of the output, FreeMarker just uses a `Writer` (as opposed to an `OutputStream`), so it can't influence that.

Comment: Thanks, it makes more sense now, however I don't create the OutputStream instance, I suppose it is created by Spring. When debugging I can see it uses org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter, but I can't find any reference to encoding with it. Thanks

Comment: The charset used by Catalina most certainly depends on the "characterEncoding" property of the `HttpServletResponse`. So if you have something like `response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");` in your MVC Controller, that might solves it. But, it's maybe not the proper way of setting the encoding in Spring.

Comment: Okay thanks! Using HttpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding() did the trick!

Answer (score 9):

I was able to resolve a similar issue with non-standard symbols (like ™) by setting the content-type on the FreeMarkerViewResolver:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
...
    <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
...
</bean>
```

Answer (score 9):

For DROPWIZARD Users: passing through the UTF-8 Charset in the constructor worked out:

```
import io.dropwizard.views.View;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class SomeView extends View {
    public SomeView() {
        super("/views/some.ftl", Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the [freemarker servlet](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_misc_servlet.html) there exist init parameters for encoding of template and output. You might compare it with your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In a Dropwizard project this can be fixed by adding `<#ftl encoding="utf-8">` at the start of the template file, as described in [FreeMarkers’s FAQ](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_misc_charset.html). This works because [Dropwizard uses the encoding of the template for the output](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/v2.0.20/dropwizard-views-freemarker/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/views/freemarker/FreemarkerViewRenderer.java#L96).