# FreeMarker Not Able Display Chinese Character

Tags: java, freemarker

First time use FreeMarker on JAVA project and stack on configure the chinese character.

I tried a lot of examples to fix the code like below, but it still not able to make it.

```
// Free-marker configuration object              
Configuration conf = new Configuration();            
conf.setTemplateLoader(new ClassTemplateLoader(getClass(), "/"));   
conf.setLocale(Locale.CHINA);
conf.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

// Load template from source folder              
Template template = conf.getTemplate(templatePath);                                 
template.setEncoding("UTF-8");

// Get Free-Marker output value              
Writer output = new StringWriter();              
template.process(input, output);

// Map Email Full Content            
EmailNotification email = new EmailNotification();  
email.setSubject(subject);              
.......
```

Saw some example request to make changes on the freemarker.properties but i have no this file. I just import the .jar file and use it.

Kindly advise what should i do to make it display chinese character.

Comment: What makes you think it is not displaying Chinese characters correctly?

Comment: Is your template file correctly UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Freemarker encoding - question marks in the place of accented characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559658/freemarker-encoding-question-marks-in-the-place-of-accented-characters)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen hi, may i know how to ensure my template been encoded? I tried <#ftl encoding='UTF-8'> inside my template, but it's not help.

Comment: @Raedwald, hi, i tried set the default encoding as above i showed. But doesn't help.

Comment: Actually i doing 2 templates, one template able display chinese word, another one not able. The way i implement is same even the content of the template is same. Is that any hidden error caused behind or setting i shld do ?

Comment: The character encoding of the (source) template is decided by the editor you use to create/edit the template and save it to disk. So the question becomes: what editor do you use to edit the template, and is it configured to output UTF-8.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen hi, i'm using eclipse text editor to edit the content. It that correct? but the file format is (.ftl).

Comment: In Eclipse, Window -> Preferences -> Workspace, what's your default encoding set to? What about Project -> Properties -> Resource?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen hi, 
1st > Workspace > Text File Encoding > "Default(UTF-8)", 
2nd > Project > Resource > Text File Encoding > "Inherited from container(UTF-8)". my setting correct?

Comment: I tired my testClass, it able to display chinese character in the same (.ftl) file. 
Example (Hi : Hello World! 王八蛋)

Comment: You should be more specific about what the problem is... Are you getting question marks or something else? Is the problematic text coming from the FTL file or from the data-model? Are the characers already wrong in the `String` that the `StringWriter` accumulates, or it becomes distorted later?

Comment: was figure out the issue, it was not the coding error or any setting error. It caused by the outlook content do not appear chinese word when the subject do not contain any chinese word. anyway, guys thanks for advise.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the problem?

Anyway, `cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");` should be enough, assuming your template files are indeed in UTF-8. But, another place where you have to ensure proper encoding is when you convert the the template output back to "binary" from UNICODE text. So FreeMarker sends its output into a `Writer`, so everything is UNICODE so far, but then you will have an `OutputStreamWriter` or something like that, and that has to use charset (UTF-8 probably) that can encode Chinese characters.

Comment: Writers on Windows don't default to UTF-8, so this really can cause problems.

Comment: @ddekany kindly see my main post again, i updated the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your file encoding of your .ftl template files by saving over them in your IDE or notepad, and changing the encoding in the save dialog. 
There should be an Encoding dropdown at the bottom of the save dialog.